# Spring Boot 2.0.5 still using Spring version 4.3.8.RELEASE

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am using Spring boot version 2.0.5 in an IntelliJIdea project. Here is my maven.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />

        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I verified that it was using `Spring version 4.3.8` even though, Springboot's documentation clearly says that `Springboot 2.0.X` uses Spring version `5.0.X`.

After this I overrode the `<spring.version>` property in the POM file, as shown below:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>5.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>`
```

Still, the version of Spring my project uses is `4.3.8`!

`System.out.println("version: " + SpringVersion.getVersion());` . outputs `4.3.8.RELEASE`.

Can anyone help me understand how to actually update Springboot's version of the Spring framework used?

Comment: What does `mvn dependency:tree` say to the spring version?

Comment: I got it working. I believe I had to invalidate caches and restart.

Answer (score 2):

As per SpringBoot documentation and dependency matrix, SpringBoot 2+ uses Spring Framework 5 (SpringBoot 3+ uses Spring Framework 6).

This should be a local cache issue.
Please try to refresh the cache and try again.